In snowflake using a custom role need to be able to query all results from SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY
We would like to use a specific custom role and using the role being able to see all results from below (SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY)
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY())

We already granted MONITOR access on all users to this role and also MONITOR access on all warehouses to this role (applied the generated script using below 2 queries as ACCOUNTADMIN and SYSADMIN and USERADMIN roles).
SHOW USERS;

SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT('GRANT MONITOR ON USER "', "name", '" TO ROLE <CUSTOM_ROLE>;'), '
') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY "name") AS GRANT_MONITOR
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));

SHOW WAREHOUSES;

SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT('GRANT MONITOR ON WAREHOUSE "', "name", '" TO ROLE <CUSTOM_ROLE>;'), '
') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY "name") AS GRANT_MONITOR
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));

But when we query below we only see results for limited users. How can we retrieve all/any result from SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY, what rights we are missing that are not assigned to our specific role?
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY())


Are you hitting the 10k row limit? If not, can you work out which queries are missing? Are they for a specific user or role or warehouse? If you run, for example, QUERY_HISTORY_BY_USER, for a specific user does it return all records for that user when your original query doesn’t?

Actually if I do count(1) I get 100 rows, I guess that's the default. I can change it up to 10,000 as you said. Which works. Awesome

Any reason you aren't simply granting that role permission to ACCOUNT_USAGE query history?  You could also create a view over account usage that only that role has access to.  Just curious as to the requirement to use information_schema for this.

We first pull from account_usage query history but for current query_history there are misses, for those we fill the rest from information_schema.query_history. It's like a waterfall
